# Compare multiple lists containing multiple elements

Tags: python

In my dataset, I have columns called 'ACCOUNT_NAME' and 'INSTITUTIONAL_SECTOR_CODE' where some of these account names have words like elements in list1 and corresponding institutional sector codes like elements in list2.
`list1 = ['limited','Hotel','Company','Restaurant','Sacco'] and list2 = [''NFCPVT','OLENT','MENT','SENT','MFI']`, I'm currently hard coding it (Please check out code sample of what I did on [github](https://github.com/VioletteM/Python-Function/blob/main/account_name_and_inst_sec_codes_constistency.py)) but i want to simplify my function. My thought process is to be able to loop through list1 get the first four elements compare them with corresponding elements in list2 i.e. the first element in list1 can be paired with any of the first four elements in list2 and the last element in list1 (Sacco) should only correspond to 'MFI' in list2. Then output a list or value count of institutional sector codes that are not present in list2.

Any idea how i can simplify it? Appreciate any help!

Code sample;

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def acc_name_and_inst_sec_codes_consistency(df):
    
    #account name
    
    Comp_acc_name = ['ltdt','limited','Hotel','Company','Restaurant','Consultant','technologies','Service','atelier','quincaillerie']
    
    Sacco_acc_name = ['SACCO']

    inst_sector_code_comp_acc_name = ['NFCPVT','OLENT','MENT','SENT','NFCPUB']
    
    inst_sector_code_Sacco_acc_name = ['MFI']

    Filtered_comp_acc_name = 
    df[df['ACCOUNT_NAME'].str.contains('|'.join(Comp_acc_name), 
    case=False)]
    
    Filtered_sacco_acc_name = 
    df[df['ACCOUNT_NAME'].str.contains('|'.join(Sacco_acc_name), 
    case=False)]

    print('Below are institutional sector codes that shouldnot be 
    included for the Account name with',\
      Comp_acc_name,'in it\n\n',Filtered_comp_acc_name[~Filtered_comp_acc_name['INSTITUTIONAL_SECTOR_CODE'].\
      isin(inst_sector_code_comp_acc_name)]['INSTITUTIONAL_SECTOR_CODE_DESC'].value_counts().\
      rename_axis('INSTITUTIONAL_SECTOR_CODE_DESC').reset_index(name='counts').sort_values('counts', ascending = False).\
      to_string(index=False),'\n\n' 'Below are institutional sector codes that shouldnot be included for the Account name with', Sacco_acc_name,'in it\n\n',Filtered_sacco_acc_name[~Filtered_sacco_acc_name['INSTITUTIONAL_SECTOR_CODE'].\
    isin(inst_sector_code_Sacco_acc_name)]['INSTITUTIONAL_SECTOR_CODE_DESC'].value_counts().\
      rename_axis('INSTITUTIONAL_SECTOR_CODE_DESC').reset_index(name='counts').sort_values('counts', ascending = False).\
      to_string(index=False))
```

Sample output;

```
Below are institutional sector codes that shouldnot be included for the Account name with ['ltdt', 'limited', 'Hotel', 'Company', 'Restaurant', 'Consultant', 'technologies', 'Service', 'atelier', 'quincaillerie'] in it

 INSTITUTIONAL_SECTOR_CODE_DESC  counts
                Not Applicable   11012
                   Individuals    1537
                     Insurance       9
    MFI/SACCO (Deposit Taking)       3 

Below are institutional sector codes that shouldnot be included for the Account name with ['SACCO'] in it

     INSTITUTIONAL_SECTOR_CODE_DESC  counts
                    Not Applicable    1001
                       Individuals      28
 Non Financial Companies - Private       1
```

Comment: Please include a [mre] in your question. We should not have to go to an external source to see your code.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi added code sample for reference. Thank you